# android google play service out of date

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am trying to add a Google Map in my activity (I already done it) and whenever I go on the activity I got a message saying that I need to update my Google play's services (obviously they are)

Also I am using a real device I am not emulating anything.

Here is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.soueuls.swipe" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AdministrationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_administration" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GroupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_group" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_news" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DiderotActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_diderot" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_camera" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBiMMFo5BneueuerEp69XUNdaCgA1wkVA8" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my activity's xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.soueuls.swipe.MapActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my activity file :

```
package com.example.soueuls.swipe;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        BaseMenuHandler.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        BaseMenuHandler.onOptionItemSelected(item, this);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I think your device older version of google play services so try to update google play services from play store and let check what happen?

Comment: Everything is up to date.

Comment: what is value of google_play_services_version ?

Comment: It's 5208000 and I get a message in logcat saying "W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5208000 but found 5089038"

Comment: try to change this value to 4452000 and check what happens ?

Comment: As I expected I got an exception saying "W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date. Requires 5208000 but found 5089038" plus something saying "You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />"

Comment: you also missing missing "<use-sdk>" tag something like this <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" /> in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I am using Android-Studio as a development tool and I think that this is managed by Gradle in this case.

Comment: at-least try one time then you can sure problem is not due to this reason.

Comment: Just added it
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />

Did not solve any problem.

Comment: which device have you using ?

Comment: I am using a Nexus 5 from Google and I am on Linux Xubuntu.

Comment: when your app open app at time have you get any dialog for update google play services ?

Comment: On my precedent test app I never got one, just got the message on this attempt.

Comment: I also encountered same problem. I was using latest version of Google play services (5.2.08). I moved Google play service version 5.0.89. Now I am not getting that error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the problem myself.

It seems that the latest "Google play service" though my IDE was not good to publish apps and use API. I had to replace inside the local build gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

by:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```